# Submit a form in Struts : in an iframe context and without having the form fields as attribute of the action

Tags: forms, iframe, struts, submit, action

I have got a tricky problem. I have a page with three iframes, each one calls a struts action to display the content.

Now, in one of the iframes, there is a (struts) form and a (struts) submit button. In another frame, an historic of the last actions performed by the user. When the submit button is clicked, I would like the form to be submitted and the entire page reloaded, so that the historic is up to date.

Last problem, but not least :

Let's say I have : - select1 : a struts select in the form.
When the submit button is clicked, the struts action related is called. But, I do not want to have a "select1" attribute in this action. Instead, I want to have an object that contains this "select1", lets say an object called "fieldContainer". I want fieldContainer.select1 to be initialized when the form is submitted.

So lets have an example :

form.jsp :

```
<s:form>
  <s:select id="select1" name="select1" list="select1list"/>
  <s:submit action="submitThisForm"/>
</s:form>
```

theAction.java :

```
FieldContainer fieldContainer;

@action("submitThisForm") 
String submitThisForm() {
  String mySelect = fieldContainer.select1 ;
  // do something with mySelect
  return "SUCCESS";
}
```

I don't know how to achieve something that corresponds to every point, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem you will have to do it with javascript on the client-side.

After displaying the new content of the submitted page, the parent of the iframe has to handle the updating of the other pages.
Either the parent causes a refresh of the other frames
or 
the needed information is hidden in response of the submit and is taken by the parent and set to the "historic frame" (by js).

Both has advantages but I cannot think of a solution without javascript.

About your least problem:
If the action provides a getter for fieldContainer and the name of the field is "fieldContainer.select1" struts will put the value to the setter in the object fieldcontainer.
The fieldContainer should be somewhere in the valuestack, so struts can find the setters for it.